# MySQL Syntax Error #1064 - Trying To Copy A Database

Tags: mysql, syntax, insert, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to copy over my database and get the following error

> SQL query:
>
> INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VATue Mar2021 :07 :29 +00002012323232;
>
> MySQL said:    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'VATue Mar 20 21:07:29 +0000 2012323232' at line 1

It successfully copies 8 of 14 tables, but gets stuck here. Bellow is the section around the offending INSERT INTO. This was copied directly from a database that was working fine, so any insight into how this can be resolved is very much appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VALUES (51, 54, '_menu_item_object_id', '3');
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VATue Mar 20 21:07:29 +0000 2012323232;s:4:LUES (52, 54, '_menu_item_object', 'category');
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VALUES (53, 54, '_menu_item_target', '');
```

Comment: your SQL export is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VATue Mar 20 21:07:29 +0000 2012323232;s:4:LUES (52, 54, '_menu_item_object', 'category');
```

Into this:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VALUES (52, 54, '_menu_item_object', 'category');
```

By removing the date in the middle of the word `VALUES` :)

Comment: Why does this line cause an error when there are dozens before it with similar syntax? Do I only need to change this line or all of them?

Comment: Updated my answer :) Just update that line. Regarding the rest, I couldn't tell. Run them too and see if they throw an error too

Comment: Error

SQL query: 

6 

MySQL said:  
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '6' at line 1

Comment: I got the above error with the updated line, but all 14 tables got created.